# Vertex with too many connections in Maya

Tags: 3d, maya

After some mesh editing in Maya I got one vertex with a lot of connections. Please help, how can I fix it? Don't even know how to google it.
[image: problem place]

Comment: I would suggest something like ctrl+z ...or backing up your work.

Comment: @wondra I think somewhere in maya there should be an option to optimize such vertices...

Comment: What do you expect a fix to look like, other than the obvious one of using Maya to undo what you did?

Comment: @Anko, something like adding additional vertices and edges between this long ones

Answer (score 1):

If it were me, I would delete the faces connecting to that single vertex and the just re connect or clean up those areas how you want them to look. Its possible that you might have merged some vertices by accident. You can also try selecting the vertex and go to Edit Mesh > Detach , this will disconnected them from each other so that you can move them how you want it to be.